# New I/O server worker threads consuming 100% CPU - Netty 3.2.5.Final

Tags: netty

We have a message middleware based on Netty in place which basically works as a http proxy. It's running on Windows 2003, 1 CPU x86, 2GB RAM.

Netty version: 3.2.5.Final
Java 1.6.0_u18

A malware software (McShield service) runs 6 minutes and consumes nearly 100% CPU. After this event 3 "New I/O server worker" threads are "looping" and consuming 100% CPU. They are somehow hanging in the SelectorUtil.select().

threaddump is not possible to do at the time (program started by win service :-/). The one below is made 8h later when the process is still using 98% of the CPU.

threaddump
http://www.stabilit.ch/download/sc/tr/threaddump.txt
topthreads
http://www.stabilit.ch/download/sc/tr/topthreads.jpg

Is this a known bug?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: after 14h the process normalizes for some reason!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be an issue similar to this: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/302

I would definitevely try the latest 3.6 version, if possible.

Comment: but issue #302 (workaround) is committed for Milestone: 4.0.0.Alpha3, not for 3.6, right?

Comment: Hmm, maybe, but there are other issues in connection with this, for example https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/327. I'm getting confused trying to follow them all :-)

Answer (score 1):

**forty-two**'s answer seems like a pretty good hit.
As I was poking around for the source code for sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl, I came across this [HP page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c03111250) reporting a similar issue. However, I'm not sure if they're an exact match. One of them seems to be specific to FileSystem selectors, but the other seems pretty close. It has been around for a while and has been fixed in Java 7(b12).

Comment: nice, guess your're talking about this: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6403933, thx!

Comment: Unfortunately it happened with java 1.7.0_25 this night. Tough to say if its exactly the same issue .. but its consuming 100% CPU and looks very much the same.

Comment: Darn. Can you try reproduction with netty 3.6 ?